# Message Type on Facebook Messenger using Bot Framework

Tags: facebook, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

According to this documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/) there will need to be a "messaging_type" property needed to be added to the payload for use on Facebook Messenger bots.  Will this be automatically injected into the payload, or is this something we need to handle as a developer?

I stumbled upon this as I am researching how to add certain "tags" to the payload for pro-active messaging.

Comment: The message about this on top of the page is pretty clear, no?

Comment: That documentation is from Facebook Messenger.  I guess i wasn't clear with my question. Will the Bot Framework automatically inject this property, or will the developer have to add this in as part of the ChannelData field.

Comment: I don't know what the BotFramework has planned, but my guess is that you would inject it, since you would know the context of your message.

Answer (score 1):

This issue [Will Bot Framework support Facebook messaging_types?](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4154) states the messaging_type is already set on every message and by default it's set to 'Response' and you can change this using ChannelData.

**FranciscoPonceGomez on GitHub**

> We already support It. It defaults to ‘Response’ and can be changed via ‘messaging_type’ in channeldata.
>   I will send you a link with the updated documentation soon.

In C# you set the messaging_type like this:

```
activity.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    messaging_type = "MESSAGE_TAG"
});
```

If you have successfully set the tag could you post your solution as it would really be of help to me and others :-)